# How do I access things returned by GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

Ridiculously simple question that for the life of me I cant figure out. How do I 'get' at the values returned by GroupBy?

Take simple example below. I want to print out the first value that occurs more than once. Looking at the output in the watch window (image below) it sort of suggests that list3[0][0] might get at "one". But it gives me an error.

Note, I'm looking for the general solution - ie understanding what GroupBy returns.

Also, I would like to use the watch window to help me figure out for my self how I would access variables (as I find much of MSDN reference incomprehensible) - is this possible?

```
var list1 = new List<String>() {
            "one", "two", "three", "one", "two"};

var list3 = list1
            .GroupBy(x => x)
            .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
            .ToList();

Console.WriteLine("list3[0][0]=" + list3[0][0]); //error
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the VS debugger shows you an "index" number because the underlying type is a collection, the grouping is exposed as an `IGrouping<T>` that does not have an indexer.  If you *just* want the first item in the first group do:

```
Console.WriteLine("list3[0][0] =" + list3.First().First());
```

If you want to see *all* if the items you cam loop through the groupings:

```
int gi = 0, ii = 0;
foreach(var g in list3)
{
    foreach(item i in g)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("list3[{0}][{1}] = {2}", gi, ii, i); 
        ii++;
    }
    gi++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `.Key` property, as `GroupBy` returns an IEnumerable containing [`IGrouping` elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb344977.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`GroupBy` return an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`  where each `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` object contains a sequence of objects and a key it's not a *`Multidimensional Array`* which can be accessed by index *`[][]`*.

To access the first element try this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list1 = new List<String>() {
            "one", "two", "three", "one", "two"};

            var list3 = list1
                        .GroupBy(x => x)
                        .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                        .ToList();
  Console.WriteLine("list3[0][0]=" + list3[0].ToList()[0].ToString()); 
//OR  Console.WriteLine("list3[0][0]=" + list3[0].First()); 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [documentation of `GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you'll see it returns a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`.

[`IGrouping<TKey,TSource>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a single property `Key` and itself inherits `IEnumerable<TElement>`.

So you can enumerate over the list of items returned from a call to GroupBy and each element will have a `Key` property (which is whatever you grouped by) as well as enumerate each item (which will be the list of items grouped together)

---

Hopefully this demonstrates a bit clearer. Given a class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public int Age{get;set;}
}
```

And a list:

```
 var people = new List<Person>{
            new Person{Name="Jamie",Age=35},  
            new Person{Name="Bob",Age=45},
            new Person{Name="Fred",Age=35},  
        };
```

Grouping and enumerating as follows:

```
var groupedByAge = people.GroupBy(x => x.Age);
foreach(var item in groupedByAge)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Age:{0}", item.Key);
    foreach(var person in item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}",person.Name);
    }
 }
```

Gives this output:

> Age:35
>         Jamie
>         Fred
>   Age:45
>         Bob

Live example: http://rextester.com/OWPR50756